# How to load different textboxes based on url and database data?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to control the loading of different textboxes according to the url of the page and prior settings in the database.

For example: I have a database table that looks like this:

[image: db settings]

And I'd like my page to look like that when browsing **www.mysite.com/us/mypage**
[image: US]

like that when browsing **www.mysite.com/canada/mypage**

[image: Canada]

like that when browsing **www.mysite.com/italy/mypage**

[image: Italy]

So I'm trying to understand how to design my code. Should it be addressed only on the client side, with javascript on the page load or should it be handled with the controller on the server side.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

First off, since you already have the rules. Set it up first. Second, you need to parse the url (get the country and treat it like a slug) and feed it into the rules. Third, then just use a normal foreach loop and a condition inside (1/0 or true/false) if it needs to be printed or not. Consider this example:

```
<?php

// $current_url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$url1 = 'www.mysite.com/us/mypage';
$url2 = 'www.mysite.com/canada/mypage';
$url3 = 'www.mysite.com/italy/mypage';
// dummy values

// setup the rules
$rules = array(
    'us' => array(
        'textbox1' => 1,
        'textbox2' => 1,
        'textbox3' => 1,
        'textbox4' => 1,
    ),
    'canada' => array(
        'textbox1' => 1,
        'textbox2' => 1,
        'textbox3' => 0,
        'textbox4' => 0,
    ),
    'italy' => array(
        'textbox1' => 1,
        'textbox2' => 0,
        'textbox3' => 1,
        'textbox4' => 0,
    ),
);

// properly parse the url
$current_url = $url2; // i just chosen canada for this example
if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $current_url)) {
    $current_url = "http://" . $current_url;
}
$current_url = array_filter(explode('/', parse_url($current_url, PHP_URL_PATH)));
$country = reset($current_url);

?>

<!-- after getting the slug/country, loop it with a condition -->
<form method="POST" action="">
<?php foreach($rules[$country] as $key => $value): ?>
    <?php if($value == 1): ?>
        <label><?php echo $key; ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $key; ?>" /><br/>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<!-- textbox1 and textbox3 should be the only inputs in here since i picked canada -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set condition and check the value

```
if($isset($textbox) && $textbox==1)
{
//print the label and text box 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best thing is try to achive the output at server side.
I think the following code will be useful for you.

Try to get the country code from url and get the database values into $textboxA array, and run the following code.

```
$textboxA = array(1,1,0,1);
foreach($textboxA as $key => $value){
    switch($key){
        case 0: if($value) print $textbox1;
        break;
        case 1: if($value) print $textbox2;
        break;
        case 2: if($value) print $textbox3;
        break;
        case 3: if($value) print $textbox4;
        break;
        default: print "";
    }
}
```